# Matlab or Mathematica: Need help in computing the Pdf for sum of unknown named distribution and normal random variable

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, probability-theory, symbolic-integration

Is it possible to apply convolution theorem or software like Mathematica to find a closed form expression for the pdf of `Z = R + X` where `f_R(r;k,d) = kdr^(d-1)(1-r^d)^(k-1)` and `X` is zero mean Gaussian r.v of unknown variance. `r ~ [0,1]` and the pdf `f_R(r;k,d)` is related to the probability of drawing one point with distance `r` multiplied by that of drawing `k-1` points with distance `> r`.

I don't know how to specify an unknown distribution in Mathematica or Matlab if it needs to be used to calculate closed form expressions in cases where analytically it is difficult / impossible.

In Mathematica, we can use existing named distribution like `NormalDistribution[mu, std]` but how to use `f_R(r;k,d)` ?

Comment: can you work on formatting that better?

Comment: if it helps the mathematica function for defining a custom distribution is `ProbabilityDistribution[]`

Comment: you might try asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think the convolution integral between those two distributions can be expressed in terms of _moments of the standard normal distribution_, whose expressions are [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)

Comment: I'll try to. The problem is you can't use LaTeX in StackOverflow, so it'll be hard to write down the equations

Comment: I'm assuming d integer. Is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm correct, for *k* and *d* positive integers, the convolution integral can be expressed in terms of moments of the standard normal distribution, which are known (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)).

Let *f(r)* denote the standard normal pdf, and let *h(r)* denote the other pdf in your problem,

[image].

Expanding the term (1-*r<sup>d</sup>*)<sup>*k*-1</sup> with the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), *g*(*r*) can be expressed as a sum of terms of the form *br<sup>s</sup>*, where *s* is integer if *k* and *d* are. Let the convolution of *f* and *g* be denoted as *h*:

[image]

This integral can be expressed as a sum of terms of the form

[image]

times a constant (by "constant" I mean a term that does not depend on the integration variable, and thus can be moved out of the integral). Again expanding (*r*-*t*)<sup>*s*</sup> gives terms of the form *r*<sup>*m*</sup>·*t*<sup>*n*</sup>. So the integral can be expressed as a sum of terms

[image]

times a constant. These terms are given by the moments of the normal distribution.

Comment: @SrishtiM That integral is the _n_-th moment of the normal distribution. Its value is given by the Wikipedia link in my answer. _n_ comes from expanding the terms as explained in my answer.

Comment: @SrishtiM No, the resulting pdf is not normal. And I don't know any such rule. I just did the maths to expand the integral in simpler integrals (please check yourself to see if I did it right), and those simpler integrals happened to be known integrals, and are called moments of the normal distribution

Comment: @SrishtiM Thanks for accepting the anwer :-) But please make sure I didn't make any mistake in any step (I didn't check thoroughly)

Comment: @SrishtiM As for when to use convolution, there _is_ a rule: the pdf of the sum of independent random variables is the convolution of the individual pdf's. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions)

Comment: The last integral in my answer ([this one](http://http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgj10.gif)) is by definition the moment of order _n_ of the distribution f(t) (which is a standard normal in this case). This is basic probability theory. Sorry, the complete expression is cumbersome to write, but I think with the provided steps it will be easy for you to obtain it